# How to retrieve full HTML of a child element with goquery?

Tags: go, goquery

Why does the following test fail?

```
func TestGetFirstElementHtml(t *testing.T) {
    test := `<speak><p>My paragraph</p></speak>`
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(test))
    var childrenHtml []string
    doc.Find("speak").Children().Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        html, _ := s.Html()
        childrenHtml = append(childrenHtml, html)
    })
    if childrenHtml[0] != "<p>My paragraph</p>" {
        t.Fatalf("First element html is not valid: '%s'", childrenHtml[0])
    }
}
```

This is the test result:

```
=== FAIL: . TestGetFirstElementHtml (0.00s)
    main_test.go:45: First element html is not valid: 'My paragraph'
```

In other words, how can I retrieve the full HTML of the first child of  given that I cannot predict what kind html element that child is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is actually outer HTML, and you can get it by calling [`goquery.OuterHTML`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#OuterHtml) function. As per document:

> ```
> func OuterHtml(s *Selection) (string, error)
> ```
>
> OuterHtml returns the outer HTML rendering of the first item in the
>   selection - that is, the HTML including the first element's tag and
>   attributes.
>
> Unlike InnerHtml, this is a function and not a method on the
>   Selection, because this is not a jQuery method (in javascript-land,
>   this is a property provided by the DOM).

So just change the line to:

```
html, _ := goquery.OuterHTML(s)
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I was looking for. Thanks!